# Computed property don't observe changes in objects in array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My component don't observe changes in my array of objects, when i change language. It works only after change route, but it's deserved to change everything immediately, without reload page.

Component code:

```
  columnsToEdit: Ember.computed('i18n.locale', function() {
    let i18n = this.get('i18n');
    return Ember.A([
      {
        "propertyName": "name",
        "title": i18n.t('Name')
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "phone",
        "title": i18n.t('Name'),        
      },
    ]);
  }),

  columns: Ember.computed.map('columnsToEdit.[]', function(column){
    return column;
  }),
```

I think, it should works. "ColumnsToEdit" looks for changes from i18n.locale in "columsToEdit". Next "columns" looks for changes in "columnsToEdit". When I call "console.log" in "columns" it returns expected result, but in my view nothing happened after click "language-switch". So why my component didn't change "titles" in view? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show more code. [Your code is working fine!](https://ember-twiddle.com/4f08a633849ad7567fadd340e5e27254?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

However, you need to understand that your property `columns` will always be exactly the same as `columnsToEdit`. I'm not sure what you *want* to do, but currently your not doing anything in `columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
currentLocale: Ember.computed.readOnly('i18n.locale'),
columnsToEdit: Ember.computed('currentLocale', function() {
    let i18n = this.get('i18n');
    return Ember.A([
      {
        "propertyName": "name",
        "title": i18n.t('Name')
      },
      {
        "propertyName": "phone",
        "title": i18n.t('Name'),        
      },
    ]);
  }),

  columns: Ember.computed.map('columnsToEdit.[]', function(column){
    return column;
  }),
```